# How do I make this void recursive function return a value

Tags: c, function, recursion, graph-theory, depth-first-search

so I have this function which does a depth first search traversal of a graph and prints out the nodes traversed. But instead of printing the nodes I want this function to return the node it newly moved to, return one node per call of the function.

when I call the function with the start node 0, it should return the next node in traversal (order of the nodes when traversing is printed out when running the program, along with the graph's adjacency list), which is 1 but it is returning 3.

the traversal order is: 1 2 3 2 4 5 4 6

below is what I have tried:

```
int DFS(struct Graph* graph, int vertex) {
    struct node* adjList = graph->adjLists[vertex];
    struct node* temp = adjList;

    int back = 0;  

    graph->visited[vertex] = 1;

    while (temp != NULL) {
    int connectedVertex = temp->vertex;
    
    if (graph->visited[connectedVertex] == 0) {

        if ( back==1 ) { 
        return vertex;
        printf("node: %d\n", vertex);
        }

        printf("node 1: %d\n", connectedVertex);
        return DFS(graph, connectedVertex);
        back = 1; 
    } 

        temp = temp->next;
    }
  return vertex;
}
```

and here is the function without the return statements (originally a void function):

```
void DFS(struct Graph* graph, int vertex) {

    struct node* adjList = graph->adjLists[vertex];
    struct node* temp = adjList;

    int back = 0;  // = "We have already expanded vertex"

    graph->visited[vertex] = 1;

    while (temp != NULL) {
    int connectedVertex = temp->vertex;
    
    if (graph->visited[connectedVertex] == 0) {

        if ( back==1 ) // Report the revisited node 
        printf("node: %d\n", vertex);

        printf("node: %d\n", connectedVertex);
        DFS(graph, connectedVertex);
        back = 1; // Tag this node as having been expanded.
    } 

    temp = temp->next;
    }

}
```

and here is my full program:

```
// DFS algorithm in C

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  int vertex;
  struct node* next;
};

struct node* createNode(int v);

struct Graph {
  int numVertices;
  int* visited;
  struct node** adjLists;

};


void DFS(struct Graph* graph, int vertex) {

    struct node* adjList = graph->adjLists[vertex];
    struct node* temp = adjList;

    int back = 0;  // = "We have already expanded vertex"

    graph->visited[vertex] = 1;

    while (temp != NULL) {
    int connectedVertex = temp->vertex;
    
    if (graph->visited[connectedVertex] == 0) {

        if ( back==1 ) // Report the revisited node 
        printf("node: %d\n", vertex);

        printf("node: %d\n", connectedVertex);
        DFS(graph, connectedVertex);
        back = 1; // Tag this node as having been expanded.
    } 

    temp = temp->next;
    }

}

// Create a node
struct node* createNode(int v) {
  struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  newNode->vertex = v;
  newNode->next = NULL;
  return newNode;
}

// Create graph
struct Graph* createGraph(int vertices) {
  struct Graph* graph = malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
  graph->numVertices = vertices;

  graph->adjLists = malloc(vertices * sizeof(struct node*));

  graph->visited = malloc(vertices * sizeof(int));

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
    graph->adjLists[i] = NULL;
    graph->visited[i] = 0;
  }
  return graph;
}

void sortedInsert(struct node** head_ref,
                  struct node* new_node)
{
    struct node* current;
    /* Special case for the head end */
    if (*head_ref == NULL
        || (*head_ref)->vertex
               >= new_node->vertex) {
        new_node->next = *head_ref;
        *head_ref = new_node;
    }
    else {
        /* Locate the node before 
the point of insertion */
        current = *head_ref;
        while (current->next != NULL
               && current->next->vertex < new_node->vertex) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        new_node->next = current->next;
        current->next = new_node;
    }
}

// Add edge
void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest) {
   
  // Add edge from src to dest
   sortedInsert(&graph->adjLists[src], createNode(dest));
  
  // Add edge from dest to src
     sortedInsert(&graph->adjLists[dest], createNode(src));
  
}

// Print the graph
void printGraph(struct Graph* graph) {
  int v;
  for (v = 0; v < graph->numVertices; v++) {
    struct node* temp = graph->adjLists[v];
    printf("\n Adjacency list of vertex %d\n ", v);
    while (temp) {
      printf("%d -> ", temp->vertex);
      temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  struct Graph* graph = createGraph(7);
    addEdge(graph, 0, 1);
    addEdge(graph, 0, 3);
          
    addEdge(graph, 1, 2);
              
    addEdge(graph, 2, 3);

    addEdge(graph, 2, 4);
    addEdge(graph, 4, 5);
    addEdge(graph, 4, 6);
    

  printGraph(graph);

  DFS(graph, 0);
  

  return 0;
}
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this two fuctions:

```
//   Adds a node to a list of nodes
void addNode(struct node** nodeList, int vertex){
    struct node *temp = *nodeList;

    if(*nodeList == NULL){
        *nodeList = createNode(vertex);
    }else{
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = createNode(vertex);
    }
}

//   Prints a list of nodes
void printNodeList(struct node* nodeList) {
    struct node* temp = nodeList;

    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%d", temp->vertex);
        if(temp->next != NULL){
            printf(" -> ");
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

and modified `DFS` and `main` as follow:

```
//   added last argument
void DFS(struct Graph* graph, int vertex, struct node** nodeList) {

    struct node* adjList = graph->adjLists[vertex];
    struct node* temp = adjList;

    graph->visited[vertex] = 1;
    addNode(nodeList, vertex);   //   added this

    while (temp != NULL) {
        int connectedVertex = temp->vertex;

        if (graph->visited[connectedVertex] == 0) {
            printf("node: %d\n", connectedVertex);
            DFS(graph, connectedVertex, nodeList);
            addNode(nodeList, vertex);   //   added this
        }
   
        temp = temp->next;
    }

}

int main() {

    struct node* nodeList = NULL;
    struct Graph* graph = createGraph(7);

    addEdge(graph, 0, 1);
    addEdge(graph, 0, 3);
    addEdge(graph, 1, 2);
    addEdge(graph, 2, 3);
    addEdge(graph, 2, 4);
    addEdge(graph, 4, 5);
    addEdge(graph, 4, 6);

    printGraph(graph);

    DFS(graph, 0, &nodeList);
    printNodeList(nodeList);

    return 0;
}
```

If I would have to define the traversal order of the nodes, in your example graph it would not be `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 4 -> 6` but rather `0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 4 -> 6 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0`, since I think that any time you "land" on a different node (either because you call `DFS` or because `DFS` gives back control to the caller), that "counts" in the path you're following to search the graph, and this until you're back to the `main` function, hence you've finished searching. Therefore in the `DFS` function above I implemented that, but if you need the order you mentioned, just add `addNode(nodeList, vertex);` below your `printf` statements and you should get it.

Since the function is recursive you can't really use the `return` statement  to return the visited nodes, because what you want to have at the end is a list of elements and not just a single value. For instance in your code you defined the return type of `DFS` as `int`, this means that the function can only give you back a number, but when you call `DFS` in your `main` function you expect it to give you back a list of node that got visited. You may be able to figure out something returning a pointer to a data structure or maybe returning an `int` (the visited vertex) and calling something like `addNode(list, DFS(g, vertex))` but you would still need to pass the list to `DFS` (otherwise you won't be able to call `addNode(list,...)` inside of it), so you would get `addNode(list, DFS(g, vertex, list))`, therefore I don't think you would get any advantage out of it, but I don't know.

What I did is to define a list in the `main` function and to pass it to the  recursive function (does not need to return anything), which is then able to add the visited node to it when necessary. The first call to `addNode(nodeList, vertex)` happens only once per vertex since you never call `DFS` more than one time for any vertex, while the second happens every time you come back to a vertex after having searched into one of it's neighbors.

Answer (score 2):

" I want this function to return the node it newly moved to, return one node per call of the function."

This is a bad idea, because your function is recursive.

To get the nodes traversed in order add the visited node index to a global data structure.

Note: Recursion is the correct way to go here.  Returning the node visited from the recursive function will not work.

Allow me to describe how I would do this:

When searching through graphs, the concept of a "visitor" is useful.  A visitor is a function that the search code calls each time it reaches a new node.  It makes writing the search code slightly more complex, but you need only do it once.  Once written you can adapt the algorithm to do different purposes without disturbing your carefully tested and optimized search code.  In this case, all the visitor need do is record the node indexes as they are visited.

Note that once you have the visitor written, you can easily change the searching algorithm ( say from depth first to breadth first ) without writing new code.

Your visitor can look like this in C++

```
/// in global namespace

std::vector<int> gvIndexNodeVisitedOrder();

void visitor( int indexNode )
{
  gvIndexNodeVositedOrder.push_back( indexNode );
}
```

The searching code looks like:

```
    void depthFirstRecurse(
        int v )
    {
        // Call the visitor
        visitor(v);

        // remember this node has been visited
        gvNodeVisited[v] = 1;

        // look at adjacent nodes
        for (int w : adjacent(v)) {

            // check node has not been visited
            if (!gvNodeVisited[w])
            {
                // continue search from new node
                depthFirstRecurse(w);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note:  I have placed stuff in the global namespace because the original question is tagged C.  In reality I would use a C++ class and make the "globals" private attributes and methods of the class.

Comment: apologies the printing works fine, but I am having trouble with returning the node values. I have updated my post so that it doesn't cause further confusion.

Comment: may i ask why recursion is a bad idea for returning the node value? should i use a stack instead?

Comment: answer edited above